# localnotification for phonegap android?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova-2.0.0

trying to make a alarm or reminder as per date and time set by user using phonegap android using Cordova 2.2.0 have download phonegap localnotification plugin from here:
 [phonegap android localnotification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification)
 i just reached towards its initial stage and getting errors on this line of file named as: ALARMRECEIVER.JAVA:

```
 // Construct the notification and notificationManager objects
        final NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) systemService;
        final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.vibrate = new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, notificationSubText, contentIntent);

        /*
         * If you want all reminders to stay in the notification bar, you should
         * generate a random ID. If you want do replace an existing
         * notification, make sure the ID below matches the ID that you store in
         * the alarm intent.
         */
        notificationMgr.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

error is on this line only:

```
final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
```

red higlighted showing me:

```
 R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

just because of single error unable to run this project

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin readme:

> Fix the import in AlarmReceiver.java around line 67 where
>   R.drawable.ic_launcher is referenced so it matches an icon in your
>   project

Make sure that you have an icon named ic_launcher in your /res/ folder. Then also check that you don't have any XML errors in any of the files in your /res/ folder. The R class is automatically generated from your /res/ folder and if something is missing, or if there is bad XML, etc., it will not be created, causing this error. If you are still getting the error try doing Make-->Clean. There are some other questions on StackOverflow about missing an R file or R not being generated.